# Pass a variable's value to another page without using cookies ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, html

im new to javascript and I am wondering how can I pass a variable's value from page 1 to page 2 ?
In PHP, when submitting a form I can use on page 2 `$Test = $_POST[id1];` to obtain the value of the form element with `id1`.
 In this case I cannot use a a form or PHP because I am populating the Divs containing products images and titles from my database and I need to use the `Onclick();` function to store the clicked Div's value and pass it to Page2; then populate the item's data.
How can I implement this easily without the need of using cookies ?

This is what I have so far :

**HTML**

```
<?php  foreach( $result as $res) : ?> 

<div class="main"<?php echo $res['tag'];?>">
<div class="image">

<a href="page2.html" title="<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><?php echo $res['image'];?></a>
<a href="page2.html" class="title"><?php echo $res['id'];?></a>

</div> 
</div>    
<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

**Javascript** ( get Value of Clicked Div )

```
$('.title').click(function() {
var selectedId = $(this).text();
 window.alert(selectedId); });
```

The above works fine, How I pass `selectedId` to page2 ?
Thnaks

Comment: Try postMessage, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only jQuery and no forms, no PHP, you could use the jQuery functions to store values in the session.

A plugin might help you, like this one :
    http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.sessionStorage

Comment: the plugin also uses cookies if there is no `sessionStorage` available in the user's browser.

Comment: I read the jquery documentation but I think I have a syntax problem :
$.sessionStorage( 'foo', {data:'bar'} ); where foo = elements class and bar the value . it will be : 
Set value :  $('.title').click(function(){
sessionStorage.setItem('storedId', $(this).text();); ?

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage.setItem('storedId', $(this).text(););

should be like this:

sessionStorage.setItem('storedId', $(this).text()); //you have extra semicolon

that might be one of your error

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using jquery and ajax:

```
$('#sampButton').click(function(e){


            $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'php/filename.php',
                    data:{toSubmit: $('#textBoxValue').val()},
                    success:function(data)
                    {


                    }
        });
        });
```

Then on the filename.php file, you can call the toSubmit as a POST variable, $_POST['toSubmit'].

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dustine, the variable is not passing to filename.php : 

$('.title').click(function(e){
var selectedId = $(this).text();
window.alert(selectedId);
            $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'filename.php',
                    data:{toSubmit: $(selectedId).val()},
                    success:function(data)
                    {


                    }
        });
        });

Comment: $(selectedId).val() must be $('#selectedId').val(). Don't forget the magical hashtags!